# Do "usually never" and "usually always" make sense?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-choice

When visiting the lunch buffet:

> *"I **usually never** take the spicy dressing"*

When waiting for Tom:

> *"Tom **usually always** comes on time"*

It seems like a bit of colloquial exaggeration - but is it correct?

Comment: In both of your example sentences, **almost** would be more idiomatic than **usually**.

Comment: I think @CanadianYankee 's comment is the correct answer here - certainly more idiomatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are both contradictory statements. *usually* means “almost always but sometimes not”. Try

> I don’t usually have the spicy dressing
>
> Tom usually comes on time

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted, as it seems a perfectly fine answer. The reason 'usually always' is not idiomatic (as Canadian Yankee said) is because it is a contradiction in terms. It makes no sense. That said, I'm sure there are native speakers who do say it.